# custom UITableViewCell, layout cell with default imageViewer

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have a custom tableCell that working fine, till i am trying to add an image on the left of each cell.
when placing the image inside the conventView all is working fine, but i don't like when the separator is starting in the middle of the image.

and i want to eliminate the space on the left of each row, i want to place my image there, so the cell seperator will show only under the cell content , and not under part of the image, i am strageling this separator for a couple of hours and now i can't show my content..

also my simulator i taking something like 10 sec to show the table content..

can u help me please, i know its suppose to be s simple thing, but i can't manage this to work...

thank you..

here is my custom TableCell

```
import UIKit

class TableCellMessages: UITableViewCell {
    var labUerName = UILabel();
    var labMessage = UILabel();
    var labTime    = UILabel();
    var labRead    = UILabel();


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22;
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
//        self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None

        var currentFont:UIFont = labUerName.font
        labUerName.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(currentFont.pointSize);

        labUerName.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        labMessage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        labTime.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        labRead.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        contentView.addSubview(labUerName)
        contentView.addSubview(labMessage)
        contentView.addSubview(labTime)
        contentView.addSubview(labRead)


        //Set layout
        var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
        viewsDict["username"] = labUerName;
        viewsDict["message"] = labMessage;
        viewsDict["time"] = labTime;
        viewsDict["read"] = labRead;

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[username]-1-[message]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[time]-1-[read]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[username]-[time]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[message]-[read]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var x = self.frame.origin.x;
        var y = self.frame.origin.y;
        var width = self.frame.width;
        var height = self.frame.height;

        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, height, height);
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(x + height, y, width - height , height)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the cell separator, you'll need to use the separatorInset property on your UITableView which you most likely have a reference to in your view controller:

self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)

See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/separatorInset

Apart from that, you'll save yourself and your fellow programmers a lot of headache if you design your custom cell as a prototype cell in your storyboard instead of laying out your labels etc programmatically.

Comment: i find auto layout very easy, when its only auto layout, and i prefer to program then use storyboard, any way how can i eliminate the gap on the left, what i will place the image in the contentView ?

Comment: am i doing it wrong just by trying to use the build in imageViewer ?